# AJAX call doesn't call alerts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've got a button which triggers a function on click

```
<input type="button" value="Change Stuff" onClick="Change()" />
```

This is the said function :

```
function Change()
{
    var z = confirm("You are about to change something!");
    if (z){
    var value1 = prompt("Change Value1 : ");
    var value2 = prompt("Change Value2 : ");
    var value3 = prompt("Change Value3 : ");
    $.ajax({
            url: ('ajax-call.php'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
            id: '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>',
            value1: value1,
            value2: value2,
            value3: value3
            },
            dataType: 'script'
          });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The data beeing called by AJAX

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $value1 = $_POST["value1"];
        $value2 = $_POST["value2"];
        $value3 = $_POST["value3"];
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d");

        $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_table1 SET datum='". $currentDate ."',value1='". $value1 ."', value2='". $value2 ."',value3='". $value3 ."',einstellung='". 2 ."' WHERE id =" . $id) or die('Error Updating table_1 - Error Message : ' .mysqli_error($conn));
        if ($conn->affected_rows == 0){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'No data found!\'); </script>';
        } else {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert(\'Success!\'); </script>';
                $result = $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_table2 SET status='" . 1 ."' WHERE id =" . $id) or die('Status could not be set - Error Message : ' .mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        mysqli_free_result($sql);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

Not sure if important but also in my code (reload to see ticked checkbox) :

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    location.reload(true);
});
```

My only problem is : the alerts never appear.
I tried to reconstruct it on a test page with 
given variable values and not $_POST's and it alerted when I called the site directly.
I don't know much about AJAX and this is actually my first time working with it..So my question would
be, is AJAX blocking alert() or is there a mistake in my code?

The Main idea behind this was : Check if the id is in the table, if it is update some values and then inform that a match was found. Then update table2. Else just alert that the id is not in the table.

Comment: Not an answer precisely, because I am just shooting out to work. But AJAX in jQuery requires the response to be JSON. If you want to return javascript, you'll need to use .get (off the top of my head). Anyway, this should give you a hint until someone else arrives!!

Comment: 1) You're never actually doing anything with the AJAX response in your client-side code.  2) If you're reloading the page after the AJAX call, what's the point of using AJAX in the first place?  3) Returning JavaScript *code* in an AJAX call *can* work but it's far from ideal.  It's better to return *data* in an AJAX call and handle it with code that's already client-side.

Comment: I googled and from what I've found the Update Query on Click of a Button is only possible with AJAX since javascript executes when the site is called

Comment: I don't see the result of the request to `ajax-call.php` being appended to the page. Am I missing something?

Comment: Syntax highlighting might help. If this is an actual copy paste, then this: `die('Status couldn't be...` should be changed to `die('Status couldn\'t be...`.

Comment: its a mistake by my side since i translated it into english and forgot the ' will stop reading it as a string - fixed in the post

Comment: Please try with changing data type **dataType: "html"** or you can remove this (datatype) param.

Comment: tried but it didn't change anything.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be use callbak function for ajax request. After that , According to  response , In callback , you should  call alert function

Answer (score 0):

if u reload page that will reset ur page to default. u should use

ajax setting like that:

```
$.ajax({
        url: ('ajax-call.php'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
        uid: '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>',
        value1: value1,
        value2: value2,
        value3: value3
        },
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(response){
           alert(response);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
function Change()
{
    var z = confirm("You are about to change something!");
    if (z){
    var value1 = prompt("Change Value1 : ");
    var value2 = prompt("Change Value2 : ");
    var value3 = prompt("Change Value3 : ");
    $.ajax({
            url: ('ajax-call.php'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
            id: '<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>',
            value1: value1,
            value2: value2,
            value3: value3
            },
            dataType: 'script'
          }).done(function (msg) {

            alert(  msg );
        }
        document.location = "cableList.php";
    });;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

PHP 
<?php
include "connect.php";

        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $value1 = $_POST["value1"];
        $value2 = $_POST["value2"];
        $value3 = $_POST["value3"];
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d");

        $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_table1 SET datum='". $currentDate ."',value1='". $value1 ."', value2='". $value2 ."',value3='". $value3 ."',einstellung='". 2 ."' WHERE id =" . $id) or die('Error Updating table_1 - Error Message : ' .mysqli_error($conn));
        if ($conn->affected_rows == 0){
                echo 'No data found!';
        } else {
                echo 'Success';
                $result = $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_table2 SET status='" . 1 ."' WHERE id =" . $id) or die('Status couldn't be set - Error Message : ' .mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        mysqli_free_result($sql);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```